# Como funciona la funcion emit() en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy empezando en python, el dia de hoy el profesor nos explico hacerca de la funcion emit y utilizo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import threading

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    final  = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new.ui",self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.setNumero)
        self.final.connect(self.fFinal)

    def setNumero(self):
        n = 1
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.label.setText(str(n))
        threading.Thread(target=self.obtenerTamaño,args=(self.frame,)).start()

    def obtenerTamaño(self,tamaño):
        print(tamaño.geometry())
        self.final.emit(tamaño)

    def fFinal(self,frame):
        print(self.label.text())
        print(frame.geometry())



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

**new.ui**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>MainWindow</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>731</width>
        <height>533</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>MainWindow</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="boton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>80</x>
          <y>70</y>
          <width>75</width>
          <height>23</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Inicio</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>180</x>
          <y>70</y>
          <width>301</width>
          <height>301</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>76</x>
          <y>150</y>
          <width>71</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Pero no me queda claro lo siguiente:

por que esta linea `final  = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)` esta declarada antes del metodo `__init__` y luego se utiliza como `self.final`.

Espero y alguien me pueda explicar como funciona esto.
hasta donde entendi esto es para poder ejecutar 2 procesos en hilos diferentes de trabajo.
pero espero alguien con mas experiencia pueda apoyarme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque el título de la pregunta es "*Cómo funciona la función `emit()` en Python*", lo que preguntas al final es otra cosa: "*¿por qué `final` está declarada antes del método `__init__` y luego se utiliza como `self.final`*?

No hay relación entre ambas preguntas, así que responderé a la segunda, pues la primera no la vuelves a mencionar fuera del título (te sugiero cambiarlo).

Cuando se ponen sentencias que parecen asignaciones de variables dentro del cuerpo de una clase, pero fuera del cuerpo de cualquiera de sus métodos, como es el caso de:

```
class Principal(QMainWindow):
    final  = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
```

lo que estás declarando es un *atributo de clase*. Este atributo se parece mucho a un atributo de objeto (que son los que inicializas desde dentro de uno de sus métodos con una sintaxis como `self.atributo=algo`), con las siguientes características:

- Se puede acceder a él sin necesidad de instanciar ningún objeto, con la sintaxis `Clase.atributo`. En tu caso sería `Principal.final`.
- También se puede acceder a él a través de un objeto de esa clase, con la sintaxis `objeto.atributo` (en tu caso sería `p.final`, ya que `p` es una instancia de `Principal`.
- Desde cualquiera de los métodos del objeto se puede acceder al atributo de la clase *para leerlo*, también usando `self.atributo` (esta es la forma en la que tu ejemplo lo usa dentro de `__init__()`, donde aparece `self.final`).
- Si accedes de cualquiera de las formas anteriores ***para leerlo***, obtienes el mismo valor. Todos los objetos creados a partir de esa clase, tienen automáticamente en `self.atributo` el valor con que se haya inicializado en la clase. No solo el valor, son todo referencias al mismo dato. Todos los objetos comparten ese dato.
- Si haces `Clase.atributo=otra_cosa`, es decir, modificas el atributo de clase, todos los objetos de esa clase (incluso los que ya habían sido creados) verán ese nuevo valor cuando intenten acceder a `self.atributo`.
- Y lo más importante porque siempre acaba causando problemas. **Si un objeto modifica el atributo** mediante `objeto.atributo = otra_cosa` o bien `self.atributo = otra_cosa`, **ese cambio afecta sólo a ese objeto**, ya que en ese caso python creará un nuevo **atributo de objeto** distinto del atributo de clase (aunque con el mismo nombre). Es decir, a partir de ese momento `Clase.atributo` y `objeto.atributo` (para ese objeto) ya no son la misma variable.

Puedes probar a ejecutar y experimentar con el siguiente código para comprenderlo.

```
class Cosa:
   # Atributo de clase
   atributo = 1

   # Mostrar el atributo de objeto y de clase
   def mostrar(self):
       print("Atributo de objeto:", self.atributo)
       print("Atributo de clase:", Cosa.atributo)

   # Intento de cambiar el atributo de clase a través de self,
   # creará un nuevo atributo de objeto con el mismo nombre
   def cambiar(self, nuevo_valor):
       self.atributo = nuevo_valor

# Sin instanciar objetos, se pueden ver los atributos de clase
print(Cosa.atributo)  # Sale 1

# Instanciando un objeto, también se puede intentar acceder
# a su atributo. Mostrará el de clase
obj_cosa = Cosa()
print(obj_cosa.atributo)  # Sale 1

# De hecho, el de objeto y el de clase son el mismo
print(obj_cosa.atributo is Cosa.atributo)  # True

# Así que no es de extrañar este resultado
obj_cosa.mostrar()  # Muestra dos veces 1

# Pero intentemos cambiar el atributo de la clase
Cosa.atributo = 2

# ¿Qué mostrará ahora esto?
obj_cosa.mostrar()  # Muestra dos veces 2. El objeto no tiene atributo, usa el de clase

# Y si intentamos cambiar el atributo del objeto?
obj_cosa.atributo = 3

# Ahora se ha creado uno nuevo, Cosa.atributo y obj_cosa.atributo ya no son lo mismo
print(obj_cosa.atributo is Cosa.atributo)  # False

# Por tanto ya no nos extraña esto
obj_cosa.mostrar()  # Muestra 3 y 2

# El atributo de objeto se podría haber cambiado así
obj_cosa.cambiar(5)

# Con igual resultado que si hubiéramos hecho obj_cosa.atributo = 5
obj_cosa.mostrar()  # Sale 5 y 2
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta en general pero en el caso de PyQt es una excepcion, por ejemplo es valido `self.final.emit(tamaño)` pero no es valido `Principal.final.emit(tamaño)`